# IONIC APK build error

Tags: ionic-framework

I have tried to build apk for android in IONIC however every time I do the build using command: ionic cordova build android it will always result to BUILD FAILED. The error is so generic it only says

> DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated

Below image is the full response:

[image: img1]

> What went wrong: Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'

please help me.

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, [this](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ionic-run-android-com-android-support-conflicting-v26-alpha1-and-v25-3-1/91826/4) solved mine

add below code at the end of platforms/android/build.gradle

```
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
    def requested = details.requested
    if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
        if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
            details.useVersion '25.3.1'
        }
    }
}
}
```

Hope it resolves your issue too.

**Note:** replace your version, mine is `26.0.0` instead of `25.3.1`